# I am not able to Log-in via Spring Security Plugin

Tags: grails

I installed Spring Security Plugin([from here](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core)). I followed the blog post very closely [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/). I did exactly the same as said in that blog post, but even though when I tried to log in through the plugin, I'm getting an error like this:

```
Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password.
```

Here is my `BootStrap.groovy` file :

```
 def springSecurityService
    def init = { 
            def userRole = SecRole.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ?: new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(failOnError: true)
            def adminRole = SecRole.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ?: new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(failOnError: true)     
            def adminUser = SecUser.findByUsername('antoaravinth') ?: new SecUser(
                    username: 'antoaravinth',
                    password: springSecurityService.encodePassword('secret'),
                    enabled: true).save()

                if (!adminUser.authorities.contains(adminRole)) {
                    SecUserSecRole.create adminUser, adminRole
                }
            println "adminUser is $adminUser"
            println "adminRole is $adminRole"
}
```

And ya when I tried `grails run-app` I can see both the `adminUser` and `adminRole` value printed on my console. But still I couldn't able to log in. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't read a blog post carefully and I guess you should look for yourself rather than ask for a solution of every problem on SO.

Comment: oh very sorry..! I skipped that part while reading :( sorry for such a silly question!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post has this update which describes why your logins fail:

> Update As of version 1.2 of the Spring Security Core plugin, the
>   generated User class automatically encodes the password when an
>   instance is saved. Hence you no longer need to explicitly use
>   SpringSecurityService.encodePassword()

Comment: oh very sorry..! I skipped that part while reading :( sorry for such a silly question!!.. Thanks @Burt Beckwith sir..